# No audio when I plug in my monitor with an HDMI cable

Tags: windows-7

I have Windows 7.  When I plug in my new monitor with an  HDMI cable the sound goes away as my new monitor has no speakers. I googled "how do I send only video over my HDMI cable" it said to go to Control Panel, then sounds and Manage audio devices.  However, when I went to Control Panel then Sounds there was no Manage audio devices.  There was nothing close so now what do I do?

Comment: http://support.hp.com/doc-images/614/c01063625.gif ??